# adding variables with javascript for outcome number what is random made

Tags: javascript

**Greetings everyone,**

Can someone check out the code, i made somewhere a mistake but, i have no clue what i done wrong here. Only know is, that i get time to time **undefined** on my screen. I might do something wrong on this approach, if i do...i like to know the fix.

I checked the internet for more examples, but....i saw no result that was close on what i wanted to do.

What i like to archive is, with pressing a button, that it gives multiple outcomes of skills, based on the random number we rolled.

**Here is the code i am talking about:**

```
<script>
function rollDiceSkill(){
    var die3 = document.getElementById("die3");
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var diceTotal = d1;
    var SkillNr;
    if (diceTotal > 40) {
        SkillNr = "Skill 1";
    } else
    if (diceTotal > 70) {
        SkillNr = "Skill 2";
    } else 
    if (diceTotal < 71) {
        SkillNr = "Skill 3";
    }
    intothis.innerHTML = "<b><font size='40'>Enemy Use:</font><br><font size='40' color='#00CC00'>"+SkillNr+"</font></b>"
    }
</script>
```

What i like to know too about this kind of javascripts, how do i do adding more variables in the outcome. So, that i can add more skills for example.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I was forgotten to say, i am using this in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code in your debugger to at least find which variable is undefined?

Comment: Why is "Skill 2" more than "Skill 3"?

Comment: “intothis” is not defined in the code that you have pasted.

Comment: Oh boy, i can hit my forehead there... I switched i see accidently this wrong way. Thx John BUT, is this the best approach for doing this kind of things?

Comment: intothis, is a div id, where i cast this text into.

Answer (score 0):

intoThis is undefined in this function unless you have it in a scope above the rollDiceSkill(). Also, you're if statements make no sense at all. So I changed those to.

```js
function rollDiceSkill() {
  var intoThis = document.getElementById("intoThis");
  var diceTotal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var SkillNr;
  if (diceTotal < 40) {
    SkillNr = "Skill 1";
  } else if (diceTotal < 70) {
    SkillNr = "Skill 2";
  } else {
    SkillNr = "Skill 3";
  }
  intoThis.innerHTML = "<b><font size='40'>Enemy Use:</font><br><font size='40' color='#00CC00'>" + SkillNr + "</font></b>"
}

rollDiceSkill();
```

```html
<div id="intoThis"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, i do this by a button push and aiming on a div, with id intothis.

Comment: Have you done var intoThis = document.getElementById('intoThis')?

Comment: Erm...no. BUT, how i did it above, it shows into the place, where i wanted to have. Is this better?

Comment: I did this approach on what you said, but it does not show the numbers and text on the div. While i do not have die3, this code 'var die3 = document.getElementById("die3");' works